# Static routing Cisco packet tracert

Tags: cisco, routing, switch, packet-tracer, static

Im new with Packet Tracer，
Regarding the problem of static routing, I have a question and want to ask,
I simulated static routing of three L3 switches on packet tracert,
Now, PC1 and PC2 can be connected to PC0, but PC1 and PC2 cannot be connected.
I would like to ask you if there is any way to achieve this through the static route setting of the switch?
Thank you in advance for your assistance.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Switch2 requires an additional route for 192.168.2.0/24 via 192.168.200.1, and Switch 1 requires an additional route for 192.168.30.0/24 via 192.168.100.1.

Without any route to the destination, a packet is dropped.

Comment: There is a successful answer to the question.

I am very thankful that you reply me quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You told Switch2 how to get to 192.168.10.0/24, but it doesn't know where 192.168.20.0/24 is. Likewise with Switch1 - it knows where "10" is, but not "20".

Either add routes to the end switches similar to the center. Or set a default route (0/0) to Switch0 instead of "10". (Switch0 knows where all three networks are.)

Comment: Successfully answered my question,thank you very much for your help.